# inserting iframe with same url as stackoverflow into stackoverflow makes stakeoverflow reloading

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add additional DOM elements into stackoverflow for a project.

I am doing this with the developer tools (in chrome).

When I edit the html and add for example:

```
<h1>Got Milk?</h1>
```

into stackoverflow everything is ok

Then I tried it with an ifame:

```
<iframe src="https://google.com/" title="Hey I am just learning"></iframe>
```

this does not work because of the cross domain policy of stackoverflow, do I understand this correct that there is NO WAY to make this work (no I am not working at stackoverflow and don't have access to their servers)

ok but now my main question is:
When I try to insert an iframe with the same url like stackoverflow into SO like this:

```
<iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com/" title="Hey I am just learning"></iframe>
```

it triggers emmediately the reloading of the website! this only happens on stackoverflow, but not on other websites. Why is this so and how can i prevent this?

Comment: I guess StackOverflow is still using [some sort of frame buster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155720/i-busted-the-stack-overflow-frame-buster-buster-buster)